# The roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ are 6 and $P$. The roots of $cx^2+bx+a$ are $Q$ and $R$ what is the value of $P\times Q\times R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Problem**
The roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ are 6 and $P$. The roots of $cx^2+bx+a$ are $Q$ and $R$
And we are asked to find $P\times Q\times R$ by using the identities:

$P(x)=Q(x)\times D(x)+R(x)$
where $P(x)$ is the equations and $Q(x)$ is the quotient and $D(x)$ is the divisor and $R(x)$ is the remainder.

**My thought process**
so I had set $$ax^2+bx+c=Q(x)\times(x-6)\times(x-P)+0$$
and in the next equation:
$$cx^2+bx+a=Q(x)\times(x-P)(x-Q)+0$$

I really don't know where to go from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$ax^{ 2 }+bx+c=0\\ 6p=\frac { c }{ a } \\ cx^{ 2 }+bx+a=0\\ \\ qr=\frac { a }{ c } \\ 6pqr=1\Rightarrow \quad pqr=\frac { 1 }{ 6 } $$

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:**

Think of *Vieta*'s relations.

Answer (score 2):

It is true that $x=0$ is not a root of $ax^2+bx+c$, since if so then $c$ would be zero, and the second polynomial $cy^2+by+a$ is linear with at most one root. Similarly, $y=0$ is not a root of $cy^2+by+a$.

Consider

$$cy^2+by+a = y^2 \left(c+\frac by + \frac a{y^2}\right)$$

If $x=0$ is not a root of $ax^2+bx+c$, i.e. $p\ne 0$, then $y=\dfrac16$ and $y=\dfrac1p$ are the two roots of $cy^2+by+a$. Then

$$pqr = p\cdot \frac 16\cdot \frac1p$$

Answer (score 1):

Considering roots of $ax^2+bx+c$ as $\frac{-b\pm \delta}{2a}$ the roots of $cx^2+bx+a$ will be $\frac{-b\pm \delta}{2c}$. So, the product of all the four roots are $$6PQR=\frac{(-b+ \delta)(-b-\delta)}{2a}\times\frac{(-b+ \delta)(-b-\delta)}{2c}=\frac{4ac}{4ac}=1$$ Thus, we have $$PQR=\frac16$$